# ¿Cómo valido si una palabra está repetida en una cadena?

Tags: javascript, string, regex

Estoy intentando validar que no se repitan palabras en un link con regex, ejemplo si coloco una de estas:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yYtg0VZcrLs
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yYtg0VZcrLs/youtube
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yYtg0VZcrLs/youtu.be
```

debería marcar error

actualmente estoy utilizando esta expresión regular:

```
^(https?\:\/\/)?(www\.)?(youtube\.com|youtu\.?be)\/.+$
```

Comment: ¿que se repita qué parte? porque no veo que se repita una "palabra" en tu primer ejemplo, sino todo el link... y tampoco veo que estés intentando nada con tu regex para que coincida con una parte repetida

Answer (score 0):

No hace falta una expresión regular para esto: cuenta cuántas veces aparece y ya está.
Por ejemplo, con `match(/patrón/)` y luego `.length` ya lo tienes.

```js
var cadena = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yYtg0VZcrLs https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yYtg0VZcrLs/youtube";
var count = (cadena.match(/youtube/g) || []).length;
console.log(count);
```

Si el número es mayor que 1, puedes hacer cosas.

```js
var cadena = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yYtg0VZcrLs https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yYtg0VZcrLs/youtube";
var count = (cadena.match(/youtube/g) || []).length;
if (count > 1) {
    console.log('se repite muchas veces: ' + count.toString());
 }
```

Comment: Arreglale count, que no está definida:
var count = cadena.match(/youtube/g) || []).length;

Comment: @ReynaldRamirez ya decía yo que no entendía por qué fallaba... ¡gracias! Buen ojo

Comment: Para servir :) @fedorqui